# Flutter Dev: "Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development" Error Although Already Installed Visual Studio

Tags: flutter

**Problem Statement:**
Although I've installed "Visual Studio" software & "Desktop development with C++" workload, I'm still getting the below error when executing "flutter doctor."
[image]

**[Checkpoints]**

1. I've installed *all workloads for "Desktop & Mobile" including all optional ones as well
   [image]
2. I've tried using "Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt" instead, however, I'm still seeing the same result
   [image]
3. I'm using a Windows 11 device/64 bit
4. I've tried uninstalling, then re-installing everything

**Question:**
Why is this happening? Is it because I'm using a device that I bought in Japan?

Comment: Try running this in a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt instead of a regular cmd.exe

Comment: @tkausl: Thank you for responding. I've tried using "Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt" instead, but it's giving me the same result. I added the result to the question for reference.

Comment: did you try with restarting your pc?